# Oracle IN clause limitation

Tags: oracle

As we all know, the IN clause in Oracle is limited to 1000 elements.

One point I am not sure is, can I go beyond 1000 if they are the result of a query.

For instance, if we assume that :

```
SELECT TYPEID FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE DATE < YESTERDAY
```

assuming that query returns 4300 values, can we write:

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  FIRSTTABLE
WHERE
  TYPEID IN (SELECT TYPEID FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE DATE < YESTERDAY)
```

? Since the IN contains ONE statement to begin with (but 4300 once "expanded").

Comment: The limit only applies to literals, not to results of a sub-query (which you could have found out with a very simple test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is no problem, since this is a totally different type of query. The `in` has a maximum of a thousand hard-coded values to check against.

This however, has nothing to do with that one. Oracle does not 'expand' the results of the sub-query the way you say it does.

You could also write this as a `join`, which is actually the same. This also doesn't limit to a specific number of rows.

**How to use with `join`:**

```
SELECT f.ID
FROM   FIRSTTABLE f
JOIN   SECONDTABLE s
ON     f.TYPEID = s.TYPEID
WHERE  s.DATE < s.YESTERDAY
```

Comment: Fine thanks. And how would you write a similar query with JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot have more than 1000 literals in an IN clause. You can,
>   however, have SELECT statements in your IN clause which can return an
>   unlimited number of elements

So you can use this

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  FIRSTTABLE
WHERE
  TYPEID IN (SELECT TYPEID FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE DATE < YESTERDAY)
```

But why not **JOIN**?